# Codename one how to cut a long string in a label

Tags: codenameone

In case of a long string in my label, how can I cut it to fit in my card by adding 3 dots at the end as shown in the image below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is automatic if a `Label` (not a `SpanLabel`) ends with 3 dots. This might have been disabled by your theme so you can explicitly enable it by using `setEndsWith3Points`.

Notice that this will only show 3 points if the text is too long to fit the current layout.